# Laravel Undefined variable: articles

Tags: php, laravel

I have error Laravel  Undefined variable: articles  . Why is happen ? Please  help me

blog/home.blade.php

```
<div>
                @forelse ($articles as $article)
                    <div>
                        <img class="news-image" src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt="">
                        <h1>{{$article->title}}</h1>
                        <p>{!!$article->description!!}</p>
                    </div>
              @empty
        <h2 class="text-center">Not found</h2>
        @endforelse


            </div>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/blog/home', 'BlogController@articlesAll')->name('articles');
```

BlogController

```
  class BlogController extends Controller
{


    public function articlesAll()
            {
                return view('blog.home',  ['articles' => Article::all()]);
            }


}
```

Comment: ca u post home.blade.php full code for @forelse

Comment: I set all the code

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. Probably something to do with model or db. Try dd(Article::all()); above return line, in articlesAll().

Comment: Try this {{ isset($articles) ? '1' : '0' }} and verify that variable is getting passed or not.

Comment: In `articlesAll()` can you please `dd(Article::all());` to make sure you are getting results?

Comment: @skm  return 0   ((((

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class BlogController extends Controller {

     public function articleAll() 
     {
       $articles = Article::get();
       return view('blog.home', compact('articles'));
       // OR
       return view('blog.home')->with('articles',$articles);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that for multiple variables to view

`return view('blog.home')->with(['articles' => $articles]);`

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
class BlogController extends Controller {
    public function articlesAll() {
        $articles = Article::get()->toArray();
        return view('blog.home',compact('articles'));
    }
}
```

**blog/home.blade.php**

```
@if(!empty($articles))
    @foreach($articles as $key => $article)
    <div>
        <img class="news-image" src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt="">
        <h1>{{$article->title}}</h1>
        <p>{!!$article->description!!}</p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@else
<h2 class="text-center">Not found</h2>
@endif
```

Comment: I have one row in db

Comment: even if you have only one record you can also use this!

Answer (score -1):

I could. I deduced. The error was that I forgot to remove route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('blog.home');
    });
```

i remote this and put other route  and it work for me

```
Route::get('/', 'BlogController@articlesAll', function () {
        return view('blog.home');
    });
```